How to turn a Dictionary with nested arrays into an TreeView in VB using WinForm .NET 8.0
I don't know what to do, I even used ChatGPT and it didn't know how to do it. It keeps failing.
I'm trying to use a nested dictionary and can't find a solution, here is my code:
Sub DictionaryToTreeView(dict As Object, treeView As TreeView)
    treeView.Nodes.Clear()
    ' Call the recursive function to populate the TreeView
    AddNodes(dict, treeView.Nodes)
End Sub

Private Sub AddNodes(data As Object, nodes As TreeNodeCollection)
    If TypeOf data Is Dictionary(Of Object, Object) Then
        ' Handle nested dictionaries
        For Each key In CType(data, Dictionary(Of Object, Object)).Keys
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = nodes.Add(key.ToString())
            AddNodes(CType(data, Dictionary(Of Object, Object))(key), newNode.Nodes)
        Next
    ElseIf TypeOf data Is IEnumerable AndAlso Not TypeOf data Is String Then
        ' Handle arrays or lists
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        For Each item In CType(data, IEnumerable)
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = nodes.Add("Item " & index.ToString())
            AddNodes(item, newNode.Nodes)
            index += 1
        Next
    Else
        ' Handle leaf nodes (e.g., strings, numbers)
        nodes.Add(data.ToString())
    End If
End Sub


[Edit] your question and show us the Dictionary object populated so we can run the code with a [mcve].
